# VBA subtracting two dates and creating a new column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function, I would like it to subtract dates from me and create a new column. However, it does not work, it shows me an error here

```
.Value = Evaluate("if({1}," & .Offset(, -2).Address & "-" & .Offset(, -1).Address & ","""")")
Set shtResult = Sheets.Add.Name = "NPE"
```

But not help. Below is my code :

```
  With wbMe.Sheets("NPE").Range("G2", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(, 1))
     .Value = Evaluate("if({1}," & .Offset(, -2).Address & "-" & .Offset(, -1).Address & ","""")")
  End With
```

Comment: Does the formula you try evaluating work on a cell? What data are there in G:G column?

Comment: @FaneDuru In cell G, I wanted to subtract columns E and D

Comment: OK. I was not enough attentive. Placing that formula in E:E, does it return anything?

Comment: You really need to qualify the worksheet before `Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(, 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for above:

```
With wbMe.Sheets("Arkusz3").Range("G2:G" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
      .Value = .worksheet.Evaluate("if({1}," & .Offset(, -3).Address & "-" & .Offset(, -2).Address & ","""")")
   End With
```